Can't clone odoo 17 repository completely
I'm trying to clone odoo 17 branch. The size of the repository is like 3-4 GB. But whenever I try to clone the repository it breaks in the middle and doesn't even reach to 1% of it. This is the error message I got:
Cloning into 'D:\buddhini\odoo 17\odoo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2982923, done.        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.        
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer
error: 2506 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output


I tried using git desktop and also using command prompt, neither of them worked.

I tried again by increasing the buffer size but didn't work.
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000


And also by disabling compression.
git config --global core.compression 0


Used shallow clone also
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/watagalawgbn/odoo.git




According to https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/15333, there's a mention of antivirus and firewall being the possible cause of this connection disruption. You might disable your antivirus (and firewall too if enabled) and then try again.

Thanks for the help, I tried this but still have the same problem. Now i can clone at least 40%, but then it breaks

@Azeem Thank you so much for the help, it worked. I did cloned the repository

You're welcome! :) You might want to self-answer this for future reference. All the best!

Try:

git clone --depth=1 -b 17.0 https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git

